# Multiprocessing on a model with data frame as input

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, python-multiprocessing

I want to use multiprocessing on a model to get predictions using a data frame as input. I have the following code:

```
def perform_model_predictions(model, dataFrame, cores=4): 
    try:
        with Pool(processes=cores) as pool:
            result = pool.map(model.predict, dataFrame)
            return result
        # return model.predict(dataFrame)
    except AttributeError:
        logging.error("AttributeError occurred", exc_info=True)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
raise TypeError("sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz()"
TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]
```

I think the issue is with the fact that I'm passing in a data frame as the second parameter to the `pool.map` function. Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to split your dataframe into chunks. `map` expects a list of objects that are going to be processed by the `model.predict`. Here's a full working example, with model obviously mocked:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool

no_cores = 4

large_df = pd.concat([pd.Series(np.random.rand(1111)), pd.Series(np.random.rand(1111))], axis = 1)
chunk_size = len(large_df) // no_cores + no_cores
chunks = [df_chunk for g, df_chunk in large_df.groupby(np.arange(len(large_df)) // chunk_size)]

class model(object):
    @staticmethod
    def predict(df):
        return np.random.randint(0,2)

def perform_model_predictions(model, dataFrame, cores): 
    try:
        with Pool(processes=cores) as pool:
            result = pool.map(model.predict, dataFrame)
            return result
        # return model.predict(dataFrame)
    except AttributeError:
        logging.error("AttributeError occurred", exc_info=True)

perform_model_predictions(model, chunks, no_cores)
```

Mind that the number of chunks here is selected such that it matches number of cores (or simply any number you want to allocate). This way each core gets a fair share and `multiprocessing` does not spend much time on object serialization.

If you'd like to process each row (`pd.Series`) separately, time spent on serialization could be a concern. In such case I'd recommend using `joblib` and reading docs on its various backends. I did not write on it as it seemed you want to call predict on `pd.Dataframe`.

**Extra warning**

It can happen that `multiprocessing`, instead of getting you better performance, will make it worse. It happens in rather rare situations when your `model.predict` calls external modules that themselves spawn threads. I wrote about the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54731815/multiprocessing-pool-slow-when-calling-external-module/54756707#54756707). Long story short, `joblib` again could be an answer.

Comment: I tried that using: `data = class_name.perform_model_transformation(model, transformed_data) 
    chunk_size = len(data) // cores + cores
    chunks = [df_chunk for g, df_chunk in data.groupby(np.arange(len(data)) // chunk_size)]
    labelled_data = class_name.perform_model_predictions(model, chunks, cores) ` and I got the same error:  `sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]`

Comment: The error is coming from your `predict` code and we have no idea what's happening there, Your original code was incorrect as it was passing a dataframe where iterable element is expected. Copy & paste my code to see that it works. Adjust `predict` code that it works with the dataframe.

Comment: For reference: the type of `data` is:  <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'> and the shape is `(49, 800)`

Comment: Then your title and text is misleading, as it makes people think you're using dataframes. You can use the same logic as presented here to chop the matrix into smaller chunks.

Comment: @YihanBao is clear to you how to chop your matrix in chunks?

Comment: Yes. I made the matrix into a `dataframe` and it works. The issue now is that when I do the same thing for `predict_proba` I get that: `Can't pickle <function OneVsRestClassifier.predict_proba at 0x14b1d9730>: it's not the same object as sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.predict_proba`

Comment: To clarify, when I run `predict_proba` without chunks (and without multiprocessing) I get the correct behavior

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54815305/multiprocessing-using-chunks-does-not-work-with-predict-proba for more information

Comment: Can you paste your code that shows how you split sparse matrix into chunks?

Comment: `vectorized_data = pd.DataFrame(vectorized_data.toarray())` as stated, it's working for `predict` but not for `predict_proba`

Comment: I can have a look at the other question (it's good that you did not try to put it here), but let's first close (accept?) this one.