# Multiprocessing using chunks does not work with predict_proba

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, python-multiprocessing

When I run `predict_proba` on a dataframe without multiprocessing I get the expected behavior. The code is as follows:

```
probabilities_data = classname.perform_model_prob_predictions_nc(prediction_model, vectorized_data)
```

where: `perform_model_prob_predictions_nc` is:

```
def perform_model_prob_predictions_nc(model, dataFrame): 
    try:
        return model.predict_proba(dataFrame)
    except AttributeError:
        logging.error("AttributeError occurred",exc_info=True)
```

But when I try to run the same function using chunks and multiprocessing:

```
probabilities_data = classname.perform_model_prob_predictions(prediction_model, chunks, cores)
```

where `perform_model_prob_predictions` is :

```
def perform_model_prob_predictions(model, dataFrame, cores=4): 
    try:
        with Pool(processes=cores) as pool:
            result = pool.map(model.predict_proba, dataFrame)
            return result
    except Exception:
        logging.error("Error occurred", exc_info=True)
```

I get the following error:

`PicklingError: Can't pickle <function OneVsRestClassifier.predict_proba at 0x14b1d9730>: it's not the same object as sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.predict_proba`

As reference:

```
cores = 4
vectorized_data = pd.DataFrame(...)
chunk_size = len(vectorized_data) // cores + cores
chunks = [df_chunk for g, df_chunk in vectorized_data.groupby(np.arange(len(vectorized_data)) // chunk_size)]
```

Answer (score 1):

`Pool` internally uses Queue and anything that goes there needs to be pickled. The error tells you that `PicklingError: Can't pickle <function OneVsRestClassifier.predict_proba` cannot be pickled.

You have several options, some are described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-picklingerror-cant-pickle-type-function). Another option is to use [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html) with *loky* backend. The latter uses [cloudpickle](https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle) that allows for serialisation of constructs not supported by default pickle.

The code will look more or less like this:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

Parallel(n_jobs=4, backend='loky')(delayed(model.predict_proba)(dataFrame=dataFrame) for chunk in chunks)
```

Mind that classic pickling such methods on objects is in general not healthy idea. [dill](https://pypi.org/project/dill/) could work here well.